# Method getTexture in class RenderEngine cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Source code:

```
public void mine( String[] args )
    {
    Image image = null;
        try {
        URL url = new URL("http://g01.a.alicdn.com/tps/i3/TB1kfHyHXXXXXcyXXXXlcPC2pXX-750-360.jpg");
        String image = ImageIO.read(url);   
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
     Tessellator var920 = Tessellator.instance;
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, this.mc.renderEngine.getTexture(image));
        GL11.glColor4f(1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F);
        var920.startDrawingQuads();
        var920.addVertexWithUV(50, 1, 40, 1, 1);
        var920.addVertexWithUV(200, 50, 0, 0, 1);
        var920.addVertexWithUV(50, 50, 500, 1, 1);
        var920.addVertexWithUV(100, 50, 500, 1, 0);
        var920.draw();
    }
```

Error:

error: method getTexture in class RenderEngine cannot be applied to given types;

Comment: Consider explaining what you're trying to achieve instead of just posting code + error.

Comment: It is necessary to output the image from the site by means of LWJGL